# Facebook "Like Button" Does not remember the amount of likes?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, buddypress

I have a Facebook Like button on my Buddypress/Wordpress website. The same button shows on the right sidebar on all the pages of my website.

It will randomly go back down to zero at any given time.

I was at about 40-50 likes, then the count went down to zero.

Then over time, it got up to about 15 likes then fell back down to zero again.

It does this at random times. I have no idea how to fix it or what possible problems could be.

It is on my website
http://www.pokemonsocial.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook developers will show you the necessary coding to insert a like button and process it. please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the complete guide [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-facebook-like-button-in-wordpress/) this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Facebook developer social plugin for like button, [Facebook like counter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) will generate the code for your pokemonsocial account, simply paste this generated code in you template file.

Comment: Yeah, that is where I got the code in the first place -_- I have the code on my website. I used the iframe and I put in in a widget. The counter does not work